# Add string to query result

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I have the following query:

```
select point_delivery_number, bin(time,1h) as time , AVG(self_coverage) as self_coverage , AVG(generation) as generation , AVG(consumption) as consumption
from "energy_datapoints"."formatted_group_raw"
GROUP BY point_delivery_number, bin(time, 1h) 
ORDER BY time desc
```

The result is following:

[image]

I want to add an `Z` to the time to indicate thats an UTC time format

Result should be then:

```
AT..... | 2021-05-31 21:00:00.00000Z | ... | ... | ...
```

I tried to use CONCAT

```
CONCAT(bin(time,1h), 'Z') as time
```

It says:

> line 1:31: Unexpected parameters (timestamp, varchar(1)) for function
> 'CONCAT'

Is there maybe an better way of doing this?

Comment: Use date formatting to string function, not concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the right formatting for you:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetUtcDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffZ') FROM yourTable
```

Replace the `GetUtcDate()` with your time column.

Comment: format expects an VARCHAR, but receives an timestamp

Comment: Format can also work with datetime, not only varchar. In the example above GetUtcDate() returns a datetime and not varchar.